# How to write this math equationn into c++

Tags: c++

I don't know how to write the formula given in C++ and I cant use library function for exponentiation

```
         4x^3 + 8x^2 + 9x - 18
y = --------------------------
       |7 – x3| + (3x^2 + 18)1/2
```

| | means absolute value; (...)1/2 means square root

Comment: Please don't report the same question

Comment: September, when freshmen and calculus meet eyeball to eyeball, and it isn't calculus who blinks first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(4*x*x*x + 8*x*x + 9*x - 18) / (std::abs(7 – x*x*x) + std::sqrt(3*x*x + 18))`

Comment: or write the numerator as `(((4 * x) + 8) * x + 9) * x - 18)`

Comment: @TemplateRex: Of course, Horner's method is the better choice for efficiency and stability - but less readable.

Comment: (4*x*x*x + 8*x*x + 9*x - 18) / (std::abs(7 – x*x*x) + std::sqrt(3*x*x + 18)) i tried this and got compiler error

Comment: @john315 You are missing some asterisks for multiplication.

Comment: if i used that method for the numerator what would i have to put for the denominator?

Comment: @john315 Horner's method doesn't help you with the denominator. Just keep the denominator the way I wrote it.

Comment: i kept the denominator the same and i get [Error] expected')' before'x' in this part (std::abs(7 – x*x*x)

Comment: waggili i got it to work thanks buddy and templateRex also thank you for your help buddy appreciate it